# Using toastr in the AngularJS way

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toastr

Currently, I just call `toastr.success('my message')` within a controller where required. This work fine, but it feels a bit dirty to me.

Is there a 'best practice' or recommended 'angularjs' way of using the [toastr.js library](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes. Pretty simply:

```
app.factory('notificationFactory', function () {
    return {
        success: function (text) {
            toastr.success(text,"Success");
        },
        error: function (text) {
            toastr.error(text, "Error");
        }
    };
});
```

Resolve factory in controller. Customize messages, notifications/etc in factory.

Despite the idea that code adds another abstraction, it's really effective.

Comment: Not to mention it becomes very easy to mock that factory out within a test case.

Comment: There is an an [AngularJS port of the toastr](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster) that can be useful.

Comment: I also wrap toaster and then inject 'toastr' to the factory: `app.value('toastr', toastr)`