# How to unit-test angular-toastr using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, toastr

This is a function in my controller which uses Toastr for notifications. How would I test Toastr in my Jasmine unit test for this function.

```
$scope.login = function(user) {
    $scope.user = user;
    MyAuthService.login($scope.user)
    .then(function(response) {
        MyConfig.setUser(response.data.data);
        toastr.success('Welcome', 'Login!',{closeButton: true});
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your controller function?

Comment: Please update your question

Comment: You should really post the controller as it lists the dependancies

Comment: Please don't change your variable names in you question like that. I've had to update my answer

Answer (score 4):

As you are using promises you should use $q to mock `myAuthService.login` to return a resolved promise. You also want to spy on `toastr.success` and `MyConfig.setUser`. After calling `$scope.login()` you need to resolve the resolved promise and then call `$rootScope.$digest();`:

```
describe('MyCtrl', function() {
  var createController, $scope, $rootScope, myAuthService, myConfig, toastr, deferred;

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, $q) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    deferred = $q.defer();

    myConfig = {
      setUser: function (data) {

      }
    };

    spyOn(myConfig, 'setUser');

    myAuthService = {
      login: function () {

      }
    };

    spyOn(myAuthService, 'login').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

    toastr = {
      success: function (message, title, options) {

      }
    };

    spyOn(toastr, 'success');

    $scope = $rootScope.$new(); 

    createController = function() {
      return $controller('MyCtrl', 
        { 
           $scope: $scope, 
           MyAuthService: myAuthService,
           MyConfig: myConfig,
           toastr: toastr
        });
    };
  }));

  it('login sets user in config and shows success toastr', function() {
    //Arrange
    createController();

    var response = {
      data: {
        data: {
          username: 'test'
        }
      }
    };

    $scope.user = {
      username: 'test'
    };

    //Act
    $scope.login();
    deferred.resolve(response);
    $rootScope.$digest();

    //Assert
    expect(myAuthService.login).toHaveBeenCalledWith($scope.user);
    expect(myConfig.setUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(response.data.data);
    expect(toastr.success).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Welcome', 'Login!', {closeButton: true});
  });
});
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wnJYaShIKtFDuVvTqiUa?p=preview)

Comment: It will only work if you use some kind of provider for Toastr, right? Or is it a way to overwrite this function even if you just use regular JS Toastr?

Comment: @Episodex What is a regular js toastr?

Comment: When you include toastr.js you can use global function `toastr.info()` for example. You can't inject this as far as I understand.

Comment: You would need to wrap toastr with a service or use a constant in order to unit test the controller.

Comment: I did it and it works ok, thanks. I used this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21565779/219547